# Contar Filas en Django - Pytgon

Tags: python, django

**Este es mi Modelo de Tarea**

```
class Tarea(models.Model):
    id_tarea = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    prioridad = models.BigIntegerField()
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    fec_creacion = models.DateField()
    fec_ini = models.DateField()
    fec_ter = models.DateField()
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=16) #Completado - Incompleta - Pendiente

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descripcion

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tarea'
```

**Esta es mi Vista en donde muestro lo que quiero que sea vea, en este caso el modelo Tarea y sus datos**

```
def funcionario(request):

    responsable = ResponsableTarea.objects.all()
    tarea = Tarea.objects.all()
    data = {
        'responsable': responsable,
        'tarea': tarea
        }
    return render(request, 'app/Funcionario/funcionario.html', data)
```

**Esto es lo que muestra en el template**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Quiero poder Contar la columna estado, para poder calcular el avance total de estas, es decir saber el total de las completas y el total de las incompletas, ¿alguna suferencia de como podría ser la syntaxis para realizarlo? Muchas Gracias por leerme ♥**

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: La indentación en Python es crucial. Por favor revisa si la misma se ha perdido al copiar y pegar el código en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Existen multiple maneras de hacer esto, te dejo esta por si te funciona.

```
def funcionario(request):

    responsable = ResponsableTarea.objects.all()
    tarea = Tarea.objects.all()
    tareas_completas = Tarea.object.values("estado").filter(estado="Completado").count()
    tareas_incompletas = Tarea.object.values("estado").filter(estado="Incompletas").count()
    data = {
        'responsable': responsable,
        'tarea': tarea:
        'tareas_completas': tareas_completas,
        'tareas_incompletas': tareas_incompletas
        }
    return render(request, 'app/Funcionario/funcionario.html', data)
```

y en tu plantilla html muestras el valor correspondiente al conteo de tareas por estado.